# Does SFTP Server Know Connection is Coming From a Script

Tags: bash, unix, sftp, expect

I am trying to write an SFTP script using spawn/expect. When I log in "manually" from the unix prompt i have no problems. When my script logs in I get "permission denied, please try again" after sending the password.

My script is a copy of something found on SO:

```
spawn sftp user@target
expect "password:"
send "mypassword\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
```

It appears to send the password but the server says "permission denied, please try again".

Does the server know I'm using spawn/expect and is blocking it somehow?  Or is the issue in my script? I will push back on the vendor if this could be caused by their SFTP service. But again, I can type `sftp user@target` from the unix prompt and enter the password and it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you supposed to send `\r` instead of `\n` at the end of the strings?

Comment: I can't recreate the problem, it works fine with  a test user for me just changing the password and user/host from your sample.  Make sure you have the correct password and user I guess

Comment: `Password:` in place of `password:`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I just figured it out.  I needed to escape a character in the password string. Sorry for the dumb question! Will close now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions set up in the target directory?  I'd SSH in and make sure that the directory is set read/write.